# issue in working with SwipeDeck2 lib

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I've used [SwipeDeck2](https://github.com/aaronbond/SwipeDeck2), I set every thing and it is working, but I have one issue that is I can not set *OnClickListener* correctly on one of the views in card I have layout as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_cv"
    style="@style/CardViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="24dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <org.team.asl.me_c.ui.DynamicHeightImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:heightRatio="1.0"
                android:background="@color/grey_white_1000"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:background="@color/indigo_A200"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                <TextView android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/display_name_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="22sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipChildren="true">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnLike"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_outline_grey" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/like_tv"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_green_rounded_rect"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:text="LIKE"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nope_tv"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_red_rounded_rect"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="NOPE"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and the adapter as

```
public class SwipeDeckAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> data;
    private Context context;

    private int countLike = 0;
    private ImageButton btnLike;

    //private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

    public SwipeDeckAdapter(List<String> data, Context context) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;       
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            // normally use a viewholder
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_card, parent, false);
        }
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.display_name_tv)).setText(data.get(position));
        btnLike = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnLike);

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String item = (String)getItem(position);
                Log.e("MainActivity", item);
            }
        });

        btnLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                countLike ++;
                Log.e("LIKE_CONT", " is " + countLike);
                btnLike.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart_red));

                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked at index ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}
```

I want to add click listener on btnLike and want to change the image resource in method

```
btnLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    countLike ++;
                    Log.e("LIKE_CONT", " is " + countLike);
                    btnLike.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart_red));

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked at index ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

but result is

[image]

means the image resource of btnLike is not changed in current card but as I shuffle cards and see on the other card the image resource of btnLike is changed any suggestions how to see that bit of code so that it can work properly...